# Имеет ли смысл жертвовать понятностью имён CSS-классов ради того, чтобы их укоротить?

Tags: html, css

Оперируя в Google Drive, решил интереса ради с помощью средств разработчика браузера посмотреть разметку. Увидел, что широко используются неосмысляемые, но короткие (относительно) имена классов. Вот фрагмент разметки Google Drive:

```
<div class="a-s-tb-sc-Ja-Q-x a-s-tb-Kg-Q a-s-tb-kl-Gd-Kf">
   <div class="a-s-tb-pa" guidedhelpid="main_container">
      <div id=":p" class="a-S a-s-tb-pa a-Zm a-S-j-ub-Xc-Om a-S-j-ub-xTMeO Hb-ja-hc" role="main">
         <div class="a-s-tb-sc-Ja a-s-tb-Pe a-s-tb-sc-Ja-fk a-S-x-j">
            <div class="a-s-tb-sc-Ja-Q a-s-tb-sc-Ja-Q-Nm a-s-tb-Pe-Q ">
               <div class="a-s-tb-sc-Ja-Q-x a-s-tb-Pe-Q">
```

Раз гуру разметки из компании Google использую такие имена классов, значит на это должна быть причина. Я же на данный момент широко практикую хотя и очень длинные, но понятные имена классов и ID, причём понятные не только себе. Например:

```
<button class="localDesign-button controlPanel-button localDesign-button-primary">OK</button>
```

- `localDesign-button` - класс, в котором описыавется общий вид для всех кнопок в соответствии с дизайном сайта. Здесь я не сокращаю префикс`localDesign-` до `ld-`, потому что смысл этой аббревиатуры кроме меня никто не будет знать.
- `controlPanel-button` - класс, сооветствующий группе кнопок какого-нибудь тулбара. В CSS свойства данного класса могут быть и не описаны, но этот класс нужен для того, чтобы из JS-скрипта выбирать все кнопки этой группы.
- `localDesign-button-primary` - класс для нажатой кнопки-переключателя.

Хотя `localDesign-button localDesign-button-primary` в html смотрится не очень лакончино, писать эти имена в CSS-препроцессоре - одно удовольствие:

```
localDesign-{
    &-button{
        &-primary{

        }
        &-secondary{

        }
        &-inactive{

        }
    }
}
```

Итак, стоит ли стремиться к понятности классов (что особенно важно для проектов, над которыми работают несколько разработчиков) или же имеет смысл сокращать их ради минимизации HTML-файла?

Comment: Этим занимаются автоматические препроцессоры-сокращалки

Answer (score 1):

Уверен на 99.9%, что в оргинальном css там человекопонятные названия, которые потом пропускаются через какой нибудь сборщик с плагином навроде CSS-uglify. Сокращать классы ради минимизации стоит на этом этапе. а не во время разработки, тем более если вы уже используете препроцессор

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Вы всё правильно говорите, но ведь если можно при помощи какой-нибудь gulp-утилиты заменить имена классов в css на короткие одновременно с минификацией, то это же нужно сделать и во всех HTML-файлах. Технически, это реализуемая задача, но есть ли такие утилиты?

Comment: [Я не в курсе](http://bit.ly/2rvfRZ9)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно ознакомиться с различными методологиями написания CSS. Тот же ACSS (Atomic CSS) предполагает из «margin-top: 1px» создание класса «mt-1», что в принципе, будет понятно не только вам, если немного разобраться во всем деле.

Comment: Тогда классы указывают непосредственно на оформление, а не на семантику, что нарушает всю суть CSS и принципиально не отличается он инлайн-стилей

Comment: ACSS далеко не единственная методология написания CSS, в данном случае была выбрана в качестве примера. Методологии стоит использовать в зависимости от проекта и от удобства ее использования. А классы в духе "m-t-10" вполне неплохо живут внутри bootstrap.

Comment: Да-да, я ненавижу Bootstrap :)